# Regex for a custom link (url) structure verification (preg_match, PHP)

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

I plan to allow reader to create links in a custom way. I think it will be easier for the ones who are not used to write html opening+closing tags.

### allowed & required custom linking structure

```
++visible text part==invisible address part++
```

a valid structured example:
`++stack overflow==http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask++`

### my requirements

Of course a user can input more than 1 link.

1. So I have to check every linking attempt. If all of links structure
   is formatted as `++visible text part==invisible address part++`
2. then I will  need to verify & validate the *invisible address part*
3. lastly I will strip the tags (if any or not) from *visible text part*

### my question

So I require your help for the `preg_match` `pattern` **to verify the custom linking structure**. Please also be aware that I will need 2 parts (that are:*left* part of `==` *visible text part* AND *right* part of `==` *invisible address part* matched seperately for my 2nd and 3rd requirements.

### my unsuccessful trial was

```
/++(.+)==(.+)++/
```

thanks, BR

Comment: Why don't you use Markdown? You can use `preg_replace_callback` for your 2nd and 3rd requirement, the pattern you have to write yourself

Comment: I will allow only few tags and don't want to use complex 3rd party codes. Since I can't code regex, I don't have pattern code. But I can handle my 2nd and 3rd requirements.

Comment: What have you tried? The regex for this isn't hard at all. I can imagine that you could get stuck at some point with your regex. But therefor it's good to show us what you tried. At the same time this won't give us the feeling that we're doing all the "hard" work for you while you sit back and relax.

Comment: please be sure that I am not from that ones you mentioned. I am at very beginner stage for regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/\+\+(.+?)==(.+?)\+\+/
```

`+` is a regex special character and should be escaped.

Add `s` after the ending delimiter `/` if you want the match to include newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems with your regex. First of all `+` is a reserved sign as you know (since you use it), so you have to escape it.

That would bring us to the following regex: `/\+\+(.+)==(.+)\+\+/`

If you use it, it might actually work, but only if the markup is used never or once, that is because regex in PHP is *greedy*. You can solve that by using the right [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

This brings us to `/\+\+(.+)==(.+)\+\+/U` which is not perfect but will work. You can then do other improvements regarding `(.+)`